# Why do we have so many Ramayana? Which one is the essence of all?

Tags: rama, sita, ramayana, tulsidas

Why do we have so many Ramayana? Which one should I read to get the essence of whole?

Comment: It depends on the tradition on which version of Rāmāyaṇa would one give importance to. But the central piece without doubt is Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa. Although Bāla and Uttara Kāṇḍa are later additions, however it's still the oldest version of Rāmāyaṇa.
This is a cultural tale, and important part of Indic traditions, so of course there are many renditions and retellings of it in different langs and different traditions. For e.g. there are Bengali renditions such as Kṛttivāsī Rāmāyaṇa, Tulasidāsa's in Avadhī and other renditions in other langs.

Comment: And there are Jain and Buddhist versions  of Rāmāyaṇa too which differ from Vālmīki's. There are South-east asian versions of the tale as well.
To begin with, you can choose the version from your tradition or you can begin with Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa. For e.g. if you are from Hindi speaking belt, you can begin with Rāmacaritamānasa and then move onto Vālmīki. You can choose other version of Rāmāyaṇa such as Adhyātma Rāmāyaṇa to begin with, it's your choice. I personally began with Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa and give it the most importance.

Answer (score 0):

One must admit there are kalpa bhed as already stated in matsya Puran and skand Puran
So naturally there are also kalpa bhed in ramayanas

**प्रतिकल्पं भवेद् रामो रावणश्चापि राक्षसः ।
एवं रामसहस्त्राणि रावणानां सहस्रशः।
भवितव्यानि भूतानि तथा देवी प्रवर्तते।॥**

श्रीकालिका पुराण

प्रत्येक कल्प में राम और रावण होते हैं। इस भाँति असंख्यों राम और रावण हो गये और होनेवाले हैं। उसी भाँति देवो भी प्रवृत्त होती हैं।

There are Rama and Ravana in every Kalpa. In this way innumerable Rams and Ravanas have happened and are about to happen. In the same way the deities also tend.

Also

In some kalpas, laxmi narayan himself incarnates as  sita ram respectively.

**अन्यकल्पेषु ह देवाः क्षीरशायी हरिः स्वयम्।
रामो ज्ञेयस्तथा शेषो रुद्ररूस्स लक्ष्मणः॥
सीता भगवती लक्ष्मीजांता जनकनन्दिनी।
सुदर्शनश्च भरतो हरेः शङ्खोस्ततोऽनुजः॥
कल्पास्ये श्वेतवाराहे_रामो जातः परात्परः।**

भविष्यपुराण

In other Kalpas, Kshirshayi Vishnu himself appears as Lord Shri Ram, Rudra Lakshman and Lakshmi Janakandini Bhagwati Shri Sita. Similarly, his weapons Sudarshan Bharat and conch take the form of Shatrughan. **In Shvetvarah Kalp, Paratpar Brahm saketlokadhi Sarvavatari Shri Ram himself incarnates**

Has it always been narayan taking avtar of shri Ram, then there would have been only one ramayan.

Answer (score -2):

सीतानाथ समारम्भां रामानन्दार्य मध्यमाम्।
अस्मदाचार्य पर्यन्तां वन्दे श्रीगुरू परम्पराम् ।।

This is a very common question that people generally asks, Why do we have so many versions of the Ramayana?

So kiddy answer is are you jealous of my Rajdulare Rāghav?

And here is Intellectual answer;

See, The character of Śrī Rām is so vast that it cannot be contained in a single book as said in Śrīmad Kaushik Rāmayan;

अकूपारो यथा सिन्धुश्चुलकीकर्तुमक्षमः । तथैव रामचरितं नैकस्मिन् माति पुस्तके ॥

अतो हि बहवो ग्रन्था नानारामकथात्मकाः । नानात्वं दूषणं नास्ति भूषणं तद्धि सुव्रत ॥

परस्परविरोधोऽपि यो ग्रन्थेषु विलोक्यते । सोऽपि साधुसमाधेयः कल्पभेदोपलक्षितः ॥

कल्पे कल्पे भगवतो ह्यवतारा भवन्ति हि।लीलावैविध्यमप्यस्मिन् नासम्भाव्यं हि पुत्रक॥

Just as it is impossible to fill the vast ocean in a handful, in the same way it is impossible to write the entire Ramcharit in one book. That's why there are many books containing different stories of Lord Rāma. This diversity is not a defect but a beauty. The contradictions that are visible in various Ramayana texts, that too can be well resolved by Kalpabhed, because in every Kalpa there are incarnations of God, so O son! It is NOT impossible to have some variation in pastimes in different Kalpas.

As this has been confirmed by Śrīmad Göswāmi Tulsidās Ji Maharāj,

नाना भाँति राम अवतारा। रामायन सत कोटि अपारा॥ कलपभेद हरिचरित सुहाए। भाँति अनेक मुनीसन्ह गाए॥

(Śrīmad Rāmcharit Mānas 1.33)

Ramkatha is infinite, Shri Ramchandraji has incarnated in different ways and there are hundred crores and immense Ramayana. According to Kalpabheda, the beautiful characters of Shri Hari have been depicted by Munishwars in many ways.

Also confirmed by other scriptures;

चरितं रघुनाथस्य शतकोटिप्रविस्तरम्।
एकैकमक्षरं पुंसां महापातकनाशनम्॥

(Rudrayamal, Ayodhyamahatmya 1.14 and Śrī Ram Raksha Stotram)

Shri Raghunandan ji's character is hundred crore fold expansion. Whose only each letter is going to completely destroy the biggest sin.

First feel the depth of the Matter Who Is Śrī Rām?

वेदवेद्ये परेपुंसि जाते दशरथात्मजे।
वेदः प्राचेतसादासीत् साक्षाद् रामायणात्मना ॥
तस्माद्रामायणं देवि! वेद एव न संशयः ॥

(Shri Valmiki Ramayana - Mangalacharan and Agastya Samhita)

He who is the son of Dasaratha is the Supreme Being known by the Vedas. On his appearance, the Vedas themselves descend from the mouth of Valmiki, the son of Pracheta Muni. O Goddess! Don't doubt that Ramayana itself is Vedas.

From here you can understand that Vedās themselves came to glorify their lord, that's why the character of Śrī Rām is pure vedic character as he is himself the one who is alone known by Vedās;

रामानुकरणायासो वेदाज्ञापालनव्रतम्।
तस्मात्सर्वप्रयत्नेन रामो ध्येयः सदास्तिकैः॥

(Śrīmad Kaushik Rāmayan)

Following the conduct of Lord Rama himself is the vow of obeying the Vedas. Therefore, believers should meditate on Sri Rama with all kinds of efforts.

वेदेषु द्दश्यते यो हि शब्दब्रह्मस्वरूपधृक्।
स एव रामरूपेण लोकेऽवतरति प्रभुः ॥
स्वस्वाज्ञां स्वयमेवेशश्चरित्वा दर्शयत्यसौ ।
अतः श्रीरामचरितं वेदसिद्धान्तदर्शनम्॥

(Śrīmad Kaushik Rāmayan)

The word 'Brahm' which has been shaped by the Vedas is Brahmā Swaroop Lord Śrī Rām himself, who appears in this world. God himself shows his orders given in the Vedas by his conduct, that is why the character of Śrī Rām is the philosophy of Vedic principles only.

परं तेषां य आचारो यावान् वेदानुमोदितः। तावानेवाऽनुसर्तव्यो न वान्धश्रद्धयापरः॥
लीलावताराः सन्त्यन्येऽल्पज्ञाश्चैव नरादयः ।
एको हि भगवान् रामो मर्यादापुरुषोत्तमः ॥ तस्योपदेशश्चाचारो ग्राह्यौ यत्नेन द्वावपि ।
सर्वेषामेव शास्त्राणां मथिताऽर्थोऽयमद्भुतः॥

(Śrīmad Kaushik Rāmayan)

अन्य अवतारों का आचरण उतना ही अनुसरणीय है जो वेदों द्वारा अनुमोदित हो, मनुष्य को अपनी अंधश्रद्धा और अल्पज्ञता से उनका पालन नहीं करना चाहिए। भगवान श्रीराम के अतिरिक्त प्रायः अवतार लीलावतार ही होते हैं, एकमात्र स्वयं भगवान श्रीराम ही 'मर्यादा पुरुषोत्तम' है। इसीलिए श्रीराम का उपदेश और आचरण दोनों ही अनुसरणीय है, एकमत से सभी शास्त्रों का अद्भुत सार और निर्णय यही है।

ज्ञानं हि द्विविधं प्रोक्तं सिद्धान्ताचारभेदतः।
सैद्धान्तिकं वेददृष्टं चरितं व्यावहारिकम्॥
ऋगादिकं तयोराद्यं परं रामायणं स्मृतम्।
अतः श्रीरामचरितं श्रुतीनामुपबृंहणम्॥

(Śrīmad Kaushik Rāmayan)

There are two types of knowledge, one is knowledge in the form of theory and the other is knowledge in the form of practice. The knowledge described in Vedas is in principle and the same knowledge described in Ramayana is practical. As there is theoretical knowledge in Rigveda etc. and the practical form of the same knowledge is in Ramayana. That's why the character of Śrī Ram has been called the interpretation (upabrhan) of the Vedas.

So for such a huge huge Personality is it possible to write his whole character in one book ? NOT POSSIBLE !!

That's why their is requirements of such a huge collection as everyone has defined Lord Śrī Rām with his own experience;

तदेव रामचरितं व्यासादिमुनिपुङ्गवैः । विभिन्नदृष्ट्या व्याख्यातं स्वस्वग्रन्थेषु सुव्रत ।।

ऐतिहासिकदृष्ट्या तद्विद्धि वाल्मीकिवर्णितम्। अध्यात्मदृष्ट्या चाध्यात्ममानन्दाख्ये रसात्मकम्॥

पुराणोपपुराणेषु भक्तिभावेन वर्णितम् । अद्भुते चाद्भुतं तद्धि दिव्यं हनुमदीरितम् ॥

अनन्तं रामचरितमेकस्मिन् पुस्तके कथम्। तद्धि वर्णयितुं शक्यमतो ग्रन्थाः सहस्रशः ॥

(Śrīmad Kaushik Rāmayan)

O Devarat, who holds a good vow, that Ramacharita has been described by great sages like Vedavyasa in their Puranas and other texts from various perspectives. Among them, the Ramacharit narrated by Sri Valmiki is written in a history-oriented style. In the Adhyatma Rāmayana it is described in a spiritual style and in the Ananda Ramayana it is described in a rhetorical style. In the Puranas and Upa-Puranas it is described in a devotional style. It is described in a very wonderful manner in the wonderful Ramayanas, in his 'Hanumān Nātaka' of Śrī Hanumān it has been described in divine form. When Sri Ramacharit is infinite, how can it all be contained in one text? Therefore, there are thousands of texts of Ramayana.

I hope you would have understand the intensity, In Valmiki Ramayana, the story of Śrī Rāma starts from the time when he is around 13 years old. Valmiki intentionally skipped initial 12 years of leela of Bhagavan Śrī Rāma in greater good of society, which is predominantly his dev-leela, unrestrained display of his complete divinity. (Just like Ved-Vyasa skipped childhood pastimes of Śrī Krishna in Mahabharata, yet His initial 12 years Mādhurya pastimes in Vrindavan is disclosed in Bhagavatam only. ) The childhood pastimes of Lord Rāma is mentioned in Bhüshundí Ramayan and in Satyopakhyam.

Or if I say do pranam to every scripture and simply read Srimad Rāmcharit Mānas as I myself have read many Ram katha (even that also which might you have not even heard) but whole essance I found in srimad Ramcharitmanas because Śrīmad Tuslidās ji maharāj was not a JUST simple Poet of Kaliyuga but he was himself Mahārishi Vālmiki who appeared in Kaliyuga to explain such a huge character of Śrī Rām in simple language;

वाल्मीकिस्तुलसीदासः कलौ देवि भविष्यति ।
रामचन्द्रकथामेतां भाषाबद्धां करिष्यति ॥

(Bhavishya Purān Pratisarg 4.20)

Lord Shankara says to Goddess Parvati – “O Parvati! Maharishi Valmiki will become Tulsidas in Kali Yuga and will translate this Rama Katha into vernacular (Awadhi) language.”

वाल्मीकिस्तुलसीदासः कलौ देवि भविष्यति ।
रामचन्द्रकथां साध्वी भाषारूपां करिष्यति ॥

(Shīv Samhitā~Excerpted from Gita Press Gorakhpur Veda Katha Ank, Page No. 285)

Lord Shiva siad to Maa Pārvati-”O Devi, Valmiki will incarnate as Tulsidās in the age of Kali to translate (complex) story of Śrī Rām Chandra in to simple language.

Sri Vaishnava Acharya Srimad Goswami Nabhadas Ji Maharaj, the author of Bhaktamal, also wrote the same about Tulsidas in his book Bhaktmāl (1585)

"कलि कुटिल जीव निस्तार हित वाल्मीक तुलसी भयो"

(Bhaktamal, 129 Chhappai, Page. 131, Maluk Peeth edition)

Valmiki took incarnation as Tulsidas to cross the ocean of death for the creatures of this age.

Next from Brihād Brahmā Rāmayan (Excerpted from Gitā Press Gorakhpur)

सर्वलोकोपकाराय प्रेरितो हरिणामुदा।

वाल्मीकिस्तुलसोस्दासस्तद् रूपेण भविष्यति।।

(Sri Brihād Brahmā Rāmāyan - 1 / 78)

Meaning: By the will of Śrī Hari, Sri Vālmiki Mahārishi will appear as Śrī Tulsidās Ji for the benefit of all people.

भाषा काव्यं मानसाख्यं रामायरणमनुत्तमम् ।

करिष्यति जनानां यत्कलौ शीघ्र फलप्रदः ॥

(Sri Brihād Brahmā Rāmāyan - 1 / 79)

Meaning- Śrī Goswami ji will make the best language poem famous by the name Śrī Mānas Rāmāyaṇa, which will give quick results to all the people in Kaliyuga.

Next from Mahākāl Samhitā,

भव रोग हरी भक्तिः शक्ति यस्व शुभ प्रदा ।
ज्ञान वैराग्य सहितं कीलकं यस्य कीर्तिम् ।
तं मानसं राम रूपं रामायणमनुत्तमम् ।
प्रणमामि सदा भक्त्या शरणं च गतोस्म्यहं ॥
श्रीमदरामायणं दिव्यं मानसं भुक्ति मुक्तिदम् ।
यस्व श्रवण मात्रेण पापिनोऽपि दिवंगताः ॥

So till here you would have understand what is Śrī Rām Katha and who is Śrī Rām himself. Just quoting few Shlokā so that you may know to whom you read about is really who, Paratpār Par-Brahmā Śrī Rām who resides in Saket, is not an incarnation of anyone rather than according to Vedās he himself is the source of every single Particles;

एतेषु चैव सर्वेषु तत्त्वं च ब्रह्म तारकम् ।
राम एव परं ब्रह्म राम एव परं तपः ।।
राम एव परं तत्त्वं श्रीरामो ब्रह्म तारकम् ।।
वायुत्रेणोक्तास्ते योगीन्द्रा ऋषयो विष्णुभक्ता हनूमन्तं पप्रच्छुः रामस्याङ्गानि नो ब्रूहीति ।
वायुपुत्रं विघ्नेशं वाणीं दुर्गां क्षेत्रपालकं सूर्यं चन्द्रं नारायणं नारसिंहं वायुदेवं वाराहं तत्सर्वान्त्समात्रान्त्सीतं लक्ष्मणं शत्रुघ्नं भरतं विभीषणं सुग्रीवमङ्गदं जाम्बवन्तं प्रणवमेतानि रामस्याङ्गानि जानीथाः ।

(Yajurvedā Shäkhayam RāmRahāshyopanishād 1.6/7½)

In all the scriptures like Vedās, the supreme principle is 'Tāraka Rāma' in the form of Brāhman. Śrī Rāma is the Supreme Brāhman. Śrī Rāma is the supreme form. Śrī Rāma is the Supreme Being. Śrī Rāma is Tarakabrahma. Hanumān Ji preached to the devotee of Śrī Hāri Vīshnu and other Rishis "I myself, Śrī Ganēshā, Goddess Saraswati, Goddess Durgā, All the Guardian (Khetra Pāl), Sun (Suryā), Moon, Lord Śrī Hāri Nāräyana, Lord Naräsimha, Lord Vāsudev (Śrī Krishnā), Lord Vāraha etc. All are the mere parts of Lord Śrī Rāma. Lakshmāna, Shātrughna, Bharata, Vibhishana, Sugriva, Angad, Jambavant and Pranav (Om ॐ) are also parts of Lord Śrī Rāma.

ब्रह्मादिपञ्चब्रह्माणो यत्र विश्रान्तिमाप्नुयुः ।
तदखण्डसुखाकारं रामचन्द्रपदं भजे ॥

(Yajurvedā Shäkhayam Pānch Brahmõpanishād 1.1)

I worship the lotus feet of Lord Śrī Rāmachandrā, the cause of eternal bliss, where the five Brahmas (Shri Shiva, Shri Hāri Vīshnu, Shri Ganesha, Bhagwati Durga and Shri Surya) along with Brahma etc. always find rest (ashraya).

As this is also confirmed by Samved Bhardwaj Samhita;

नारायणोपि रामशः शंखचक्रगदाव्जधृक्। चतुर्भुजस्वरूपेण वैकुण्ठे च प्रकाशते॥
अवतारा बहवः सति कलाश्र्चांशविभूतयः।
राम एव परं ब्रह्म सच्चिदानन्दमव्ययम्।।

(Samved Bhardwaj Samhita)

Śrī Hāri Nāräyana is an incarnation of Śrī Rāma and shines in Vāikunth in the form of four arms with conch, chakra and mace. There are many incarnations of Śrī Rāma differentiating by Kalãs, Part, Vibhuti etc. But Śrī Rāma himself is Par-Brahma who is devoid of Māya in his two armed form (human form).

Again from Vedās,

यस्यांशेन एव ब्रह्म विष्णु महेश्वरा अपि जाता महाविष्णुर्य्यस्य दिव्यगुणाश्च ।

स एव कार्यकारणयोः परः परमपुरुषो रामो दाशरथिर्वभुव॥

(Atharvavedā Shäkhayam Vedsaropanishad, uttarakhand)

Whose Portion (Ansh) are Brahma Visnu and Mahesvara, Whose divine Guna is Mahavisnu, The only one who is the cause of all causes, The one who is higher than the highest, such is Śrī Rāma, the son of Dasratha.

सारद कोटि अमित चतुराई । बिधि सत कोटि सृष्टि निपुनाई ॥
बिष्नु कोटि सम पालन कर्ता । रुद्र कोटि सत सम संहर्ता ॥

(ŚrīRāmacaritamānasa 7.92.3/5)

Śrī Rāma is as sharp as countless millions of Saraswatis-s and possesses the creative skill of a myriad Brahmā-s. Again, He is as good a preserver as billions of Vishṇu-s and as thorough a destroyer as billions of Rudra-s.

नेति नेति जेहि बेद निरूपा। निजानंद निरुपाधि अनूपा॥
संभु बिरंचि बिष्नु भगवाना। उपजहिं जासु अंस तें नाना॥

(ŚrīRāmacaritamānasa 1.143.3)

Meaning :- Whom the Vedas describe by saying 'neti-neti' (not this, not this also). Who is blissful, titleless and unique and from whose part many Lord Shiva, Brahma and Vishnu appear.

Not even Śrī Hāri Vīshnu but Śrī Krishnā is also a manifestation of Supreme Brahmān Lord Śrī Rāma as said by non other than Vedās,

यो रामः कृष्णतामेत्य सार्वात्म्यं प्राप्य लीलया । अतोषयद्देव्मौनिपटलं तं नतोऽस्म्यहम्।।

(Atharvavedā Shrüti Krishnōpanishad 1.1)

That Śrī Rāma, who transformed himself (incarnated) as Krishnā, attained Sarvaatmakta (सार्वभौमिकता) by his very lilā (divine exploits, pastimes); and thus deities-sages-masses were completely satisfied on this earth. I make prostration before that same Śrī Rāma.

As Lord Śrī Rāma is Param-Purusha that's why Vedās has very exclusively kept Name/Mantrā of Lord Rāma above all,

गाणपत्येषु शैवेषु शाक्तसौरेष्वभीष्टदः ।

वैष्णवेष्वपि सर्वेषु राममन्त्रः फलाधिकः॥

गाणपत्यादि मन्त्रेषु कोटिकोटिगुणाधिकः ।

मन्त्रस्तेष्वप्यनायास फलदोऽयं षडक्षरः ॥

(Atharvavedā Shäkhayam Rama uttartapini 5.6-7)

Among all the mantras of Lord Ganesha, Lord Shiva, Goddess Durga, Lord Surya and in all vaishnav mantra, the mantras dedicated to Shri Rama bestow greater fruits. And This Mantra-Raja of Bhagavan Shri Rama easily bestows Billions and Billions times the fruits of all the mantras dedicated to Lord Ganesha, Shiva, Durga, Surya and Vishnu. Such is the supreme glory of Mantra - Raj !

So for such a huge personality it is very obvious to have many scriptures. So don't doubt on anything just read and get the eternal bliss. Don't listen anything from fools they will always try to divert your path. Just believe your scriptures believe in Śrī Raghav. So stop the minds drama just change Hare Rama. Just go with Śrīmad Rāmcharit Mānas, beleive me this scripture alone can give you everything.

Please Chant SitaRam SitaRam SitaRam

Hail to Awadh Dulare Priya Pritam ❤️

Hail to Śrīmad Tulsidas Ji Maharaj

Hail to Ānand Bhāshyakār Śrīmad Jagādgurü Ramānandacharya